# ERROR: While generating documentation for puppet-3.0.2

Tags: macos, rubygems, puppet

I'm trying to update my gems using "sudo gem update"

and getting below error:

The internal error was:

ERROR:  While generating documentation for puppet-3.0.2
... MESSAGE:   undefined method `name' for #
... RDOC args: --ri --op /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/doc/puppet-3.0.2/ri --title Puppet - Configuration Management --main README.md --line-numbers lib --title puppet-3.0.2 Documentation --quiet

is this known issue with puppet 3.0.2 or I'm missing something on my Mac?